# What does the inscription on the pot of gold in "A Conversation with Smaug" say?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, tolkien-languages

Tolkien painted a watercolour picture of "A Conversation with Smaug" for the cover of *The Hobbit*.

In the lower left corner there is a pot containing a pile of gold with an Elvish(?) inscription on it.

Is there a translation?

[image]

Comment: Minor nitpick, but Tolkien painted this for an *interior illustration*, not for the cover. It first appeared inside the second impression in 1937. The first edition to use this on the cover didn't come out until 1972,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### The side facing us reads "... gold [of] Thror [and] Thrain ... accursed be the thief", and is then signed with initials for Thror and Thrain.

**The Annotated Hobbit**

Douglas A. Anderson glosses the inscription as "gold th... Thrain ... accursed be the thief", skipping the parts obscured by the ladder.

> An example of Tolkien's Elvish script, the Tengwar (or Feanorian alphabet), appears on the pot of gold in the foreground. The inscription reads: *gold th*[portion obscured by ladder] *Thrain / accursed be the thief*.
> <sub>*The Annotated Hobbit* - Chapter 12 "Inside Information"</sub>

**The History of the Hobbit**

John Rateliff goes quite a bit further, reconstructing the runes behind the ladder, and explaining a bit about how the inscription works, even giving a letter-by-letter literal transcription. He gets "... gold [of] Thror [and] Thrain ... accursed be the thief".

> Among the most interesting details of this painting is the inscription on the massive treasure-cup in the lower left. The words are English but the alphabet used is Tolkien’s Tengwar except for the initials at the bottom, which use the same Old English runes employed for Fimbulfambi’s Map and Thror’s Map I. It is unusual for Tolkien to combine both writing systems in a single illustration but not absolutely unprecedented... Tolkien nowhere translates the writing on the cup and the inscription is partially obscured by the ladder, but the missing ligatures can be restored with confidence:
>
> > [image]
>
> A literal transcription, with vowels indicated by diacritical marks in the
> original enclosed in parentheses and restored letters obscured by the ladder
> given in italics, reads as follows:
>
> > G (O) L D    TH R (O) *R*    TH R A (I) N
> > A K (E) R S T    *B* (E)     *THE*     TH (E) F
> > TH [ror]    TH [rain]
>
> – that is, ‘. . . gold [of] Thror [and] Thrain . . . accursed be the thief’, signed with the initials of THror and THrain. Note that this is only half of the full inscription, since the writing encircles the jar and we cannot know what appeared on the far side.
> <sub>*The History of the Hobbit* - Second Phase XIV (i) - "Dragon-sickness ('The Hoard')"</sub>

**Artist & Illustrator / The Art of the Hobbit**

Wayne Hammond and Christina Scull agree with Rateliff, and provide the same transcription, though with less analysis.

> The great jar at bottom left bears a curse against thieves written
> in the Elvish script *tengwar*.
> <sub>*J.R.R. Tolkien Artist & Illustrator* - "The Hobbit"</sub>

> At lower left, the huge pot of gold and jewels so tall that a ladder is needed to reach the top is inscribed with a warning in tengwar. Part of it reads: *gold [of] Thror [and] Thrain accursed be the thief*. Other pots bear the ᴛʜ-rune, for 'Thror' or 'Thrain', kings of the Dwarves under the Mountain.
> <sub>*The Art of the Hobbit* - "Conversations with Smaug"</sub>

[A higher resolution of the image can be viewed on the Bodleian's shop.](https://museoteca.com/r/en/work/7378/j_r_r_tolkien/conversation_with_smaug/!/)

[image]

Comment: [Some more nuance on how to read the vowels in the tengwar here, but with the same conclusion as to the overall transcription.](https://www.tolkienguide.com/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=4348)

Comment: Just to confirm: It transcribes into English and not Sindarin or Khzdul? (How bizarre for Dwarves to use Tengwar and not Angerthas).

Comment: @Spencer - The vast majority (maybe all?) of tengwar writing in Hobbit/LotR transcribes to English. As for the usage of tengwar goes, don't forget that the Book of Mazarbul also have a bunch of tengwar. The distinction was more about medium than about race or language. Perhaps as something painted tengwar made more sense to do with a paintbrush.

Comment: You should edit in the fact that it transcribes to English.

Comment: @Spencer One of the source I quote includes a letter-for-letter literal transcription.

Answer (score 12):

According to [this (well-researched) Web site](http://tolkien.slimy.com/essays/ThrainHist.html), the text is:

> gold th[portion obscured by ladder] Thrain
> Accursed be the thief

Below that are two TH runes, presumably a monogram for "Thrain."  Another one appears on the other container behind Smaug on the left.